# Sublime Text 3 find all instances below this point

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is it possible to find and multi-select all instances below the current selection?

[image: selection]

For example, in the above image, I've selected a "string" text (top-left corner) and Sublime automatically indicates other strings of the same text value. I know that I can select all instances by pressing ctrl + cmd + G. But instead, I would like to select all instances *below* my current selection, not all.

I'm asking this because while taking notes from a JavaScript book, I sometimes had conflicting variable names (identical names but of different values) and wanted to change all names below a certain point.

I've tried: 
User key bindings > add {"keys": [my keys], "command": "find_all_under"}

But this just selects everything, not just below my current selection.

Comment: The “under” in `find_all_under` refers to the thing “under the cursor”. There is no built-in way to do that you want.

Comment: @poke For me, <code>find_all_under</code> finds all matches throughout the file, not just the ones below my current curser. Am

Comment: That’s not what I was saying. The command means “find all instances of the thing under my cursor”, as in look at where my cursor is currently at and use that as the search term to find it in the whole file. And by “under” I also mean in a depth sense (3rd dimension, z-axis), not in the vertical direction.

Comment: Ah I see. That's makes sense thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

It's an solution to **find all instances** in a **specific selection** without using the mouse.

1) You can do this with the help of the package [SelectUntil](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SelectUntil).

2) Add to your user keybindings:

```
{ "keys": ["super+alt+i"], "command": "toggle_in_selection", "context": [ { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operator": "equal", "operand": true } ] }
```

(toggles *In selection* in the search panel)

**Example**

1. Goto term where you want to start
2. Open SelectUntil input panel with
   <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>. Type in the search term. <kbd>enter</kbd>
3. Open search panel with <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>
4. Type in your shortcut for *toggle_in_selection*. Here <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>
5. Type in the replace term. <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

[image: Find and replace in selection]